# Azure web services does not remove index.php from URL

Tags: deployment

I have a PHP-based (drupal) website running with Azure web services. It uses NGINX, and the urls are broken.
The homepage is absolutely fine, but once i go to the login link (/user/login), it gives a 404.
I did figure out that if you put index.php before url (/index.php/user/login), it does work. This is however not ideal.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Start with the [Drupal configuration for NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/). NGINX’s default configuration requires modifications to run Drupal.